# how to optimize memory usage for a big memory?

Tags: java, performance, memory, optimization, dictionary

I have a big HashMap in java storing mappings from String to Integer. It has 400K records. It runs ok, but i am wondering if there is a better to optimize in terms of memory usage. After the Map is initialized, it will only be searched, no other update operations.

I vaguely remember that I came across some suggestions to convert the string keys as int, but not sure about that. Please help or share your ideas on this.

Thanks.

Comment: why not use a DB?  Even embedded?

Comment: What data do your keys represent? i.e Names, Words in a dictionary, Filesystem paths, IP addresses etc.

Comment: Words in English. Thanks.

Comment: What's the string length ??? Will the subsequent searches always be successful or not ?

Answer (score 2):

> I vaguely remember that I came across some suggestions to convert the string keys as int, but not sure about that.

If the strings keys are actually the string representations of integers, then it could make sense to convert them to `Integer` or `Long` objects ... using `Integer.valueOf(String)`.  You will save some memory, since the primitive wrapper classes use less memory than the corresponding `String` objects.  The space saving is likely to be significant (maybe ~16 bytes versus ~40 bytes per key ... depending on your platform.)

The flip-side of this is that you would need to convert candidate keys from String to the real key type before doing a hashmap lookup.  That conversion takes a bit of time, and typically generates a bit of garbage.

---

But if the `String` keys do not represent integers, then this is simply not going to work.  (Or at least ... I don't know what "conversion" you are referring to ...)

Note also that the key type has to be `Integer` / `Long` rather than `int` / `long`.  Generic type parameters must be reference types.

---

There may be 3rd-party collection implementations that would help as well ... depending on precisely your data structure works; e.g. Trove, Guava, Fastutil.  Try combining then with the String -> Integer preconversion ...

---

On the suggestion of using a database.  If

- you don't need the query / update / transactional capabilities of a database, AND
- you can afford the memory to hold the data in memory, AND
- you can afford the startup cost of loading the data into memory,

then using a database is just a big, unnecessary performance hit on each lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to tune [`initialCapacity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28int,%20float%29) and [`loadFactor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28int,%20float%29) also improving `hashCode()` to avoid collision if you want read at higher rate, if you have too many write you might want to benchmark `hashCode()`,

Even if this is too big for your app you might want to consider it moving out side of jvm to some cache ([redis](http://redis.io/)) or may be database if you can afford the little read/write delay

Comment: For String as key, is there any room to optimize hashCode() further? I thought the default would be best. In terms of initialCapacity, perhaps I can just use the map size 400K as capacity, so that no any waste of meomory, since i know no new entries will be added. Does this sound reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Writing the data to a database is ultimately the best solution if the data gets too big, but 400k is still doable in memory.

However, Java's built-in `HashMap` implementation uses separate chaining and every key-value pair has a separate class. I've gotten great (30%) speed improvements and awesome (50%) memory improvements by building a quadratic probing implementation of `Map`.

I suggest you search around on the internet. There are plenty of good implementations around!

Comment: Great to know. Thanks.Do you know of any good pointers to resources?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) `ImmutableMap` -- it's optimized for write-once data, and takes [~15% less memory than `HashMap`](https://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures).